# How do I check for a hidden parameter in a url(post form submission) within <rule></rule> in urlrewrite.xml?

Tags: java, html, xml, struts

I wish to check if the hidden parameter is passed and it's value and if so redirect to Myprofile.do else to UpdateUserProfile.do
<-- XML-->

```
  <rule>
            <from>^/myprofile(/)?$</from>
            <to>/MyProfile.do</to>
            <set name="originalRequestUri">%{request-uri}</set>
            <set name="originalQueryString">%{query-string}</set>
            <set name="isCommonPage">1</set>
        </rule>
```

<--HTML-->

```
<HTML>
 <form action="<c:out value="${requestScope.updateProfileURL}"/> id="userProfileUpdateForm" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">

         <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="1">

        <logic:messagesPresent>
                        <div class="alertMsg">
                            <html:messages id="error">  
                                <bean:write name = "error"/><br/>
                            </html:messages>

        </form>
</HTML>
```

I am unable to check if the hidden parameter is passed maybe because it isnt visible in url or the site when i submit the form.

Comment: What is the value of the URL?

Comment: my.xyz.com:8080/myprofile is the url since the parameters im passing is via post and hidden

Answer (score 0):

In the rule you can add a `condition` element where you can use parameter checking.

```
<condition type="parameter" name="hidden">1</condition>
```

This condition will check that request parameter named `hidden` has a value equals `1`.